# Multiple Google sessions in Firefox after recent Google apps migrations

Tags: firefox, gmail, google-workspace

I cannot be logged to multiple Google Apps email reading anymore (company, non-profit foundation).

Google has apparently done some changes and multiple Google accounts cannot be logged in to a browser same time anymore. The changes seem to have appeared after Google has merged some corporate accounts with gmail accounts (not sure about what has been going on).

If I login to one account this either

- Logs me out in the orignal Google session
- Timeouts in few minutes when the orignal Google session refreshes itself in another tab

Is there either a way

- Work around this problem by setting some Google Apps settings
- Work around this problem with browser plug-ins e.g. isolating app tab pin downs to their own cookie/session space

Firefox 5.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like Google Apps migration loses the setting support multiple account sign-in. The workaround is to go to each account profile and re-enable this setting.

Answer (score 0):

Would [this one](http://gmailblog.blogspot.com/2010/08/access-two-gmail-accounts-at-once-in.html) help? As far as I can see there are no available Google Apps settings. Quite the opposite, I read Google intentionally merged both domains (the Apps one and Gmail).

Comment: The information in the article is outdated now, I believe :(

Comment: AHA it looks like this particular setting is not migrated correctly and you need to re-enable it for the accounts in the question